# Docker - "image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform" while trying to pull splash. from scrapinghub/splash

Tags: python, docker, splash-screen

I have installed docker, and while trying to pull scrapinghub/splash -  It says 
"image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform". i'm using win 10.
Other commands and pull requests are working fine.

Comment: So....what is your platform / OS? :p

Comment: Windows 10. When I tried to pull another image, It's working. Do I have to set up specific settings for this?

Comment: Not a Windows expert, but Win10 has linux mode and windows mode. You'll likely need to switch modes before pulling that image. Check this out - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers

Comment: Switched mode to Windows no luck,  I have hyper-v activated

Comment: Shouldn't the mode be switched to Linux to run a Linux image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker - image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346580/docker-image-operating-system-windows-cannot-be-used-on-this-platform)

Answer (score 7):

Set in Docker Desktop -> Docker Engine tab -> mode "experimental": true. It helps me

Comment: what does this mode experimental mean? This resolved my issue btw. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open Docker Desktop option-->
Select switch to linux container option

Thats all

Comment: fixed my issue, tried   "experimental": true and wsl --update

Answer (score 1):

To Expound upon Pedro Es' answer, here is a picture of what exactly needs to change:
[image]

"True" is correct.  The default is "false".

Answer (score 0):

My system configuration-
Windows 10 pro
I have manual proxies setup
Docker version 20.10.2

I tried changing the container to linux using
Right click on docker icon - switch to linux containers

It did not worked for me.
What worked for me was disabling wsl 2 based engine in general settings.(I guess settings layout has changed with the latest version), then restarting the docker.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. execute `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Dockercli" -SwitchDaemon` command
3. Restart docker

Answer (score 0):

**This can happen when your user account is not a member of Local Admin group** and you update or install Docker Desktop (DD) for Windows and use the default installation option (let the DD installer run the `wsl --update` [**Windows Subsystem for Linux** update] command for you) and then use a separate user account with elevated privileges to assist you to complete the installation.

The wsl update command will 'silently fail' but DD installer will not report any errors, and you will think it was installed correctly (but the desktop-linux Builder will show an error in the Builders section of Settings).

[image: 'desktop-linux' Builder error]

If you choose to the Advanced Install of DD (where you update your WSL yourself with a different elevated privileges user account) you will see that you get a 'Catastrophic Failure' when you attempt to update WSL with this command:

```
wsl --update
```

**The simplest/cleanest way to install or update Docker Desktop:**

1. Add your user account to 'Local Admin' group
2. Install or update Docker Desktop
3. Follow the default installation with all default prompts
4. Remove your user account from 'Local Admin'

*If you don't like failing security audits, (even if you have the ability to [temporarily] grant yourself local admin) I recommend asking a co-worker (or IT tech) to grant your regular user with local admin privs. (and don't forget to remove your local admin privs when you're finished).*

Hopefully this saves someone else from several hours of rabbit holes, such as uninstall/reinstall DD, downgrading the DD install to an older version, fiddling with config values, updating the linux kernel, forcing the Docker Daemon to restart, etc. This can happen with any version of DD for Windows (including the most recent release at this time [v4.27.0])