# Docker image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform, but already using Windows containers

Tags: docker

I am trying to pull a docker image but getting an error. I found a similar post to my problem, but the solution is to switch to Windows containers, which I am already doing. Could anyone help me figure out what's going on?

[Docker - image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346580/docker-image-operating-system-windows-cannot-be-used-on-this-platform)

```
PS C:\Users\xianx\src> docker pull blingcontainer.azurecr.io/sdbackend_baseimage:v1
v1: Pulling from sdbackend_baseimage
af1a530dff54: Pulling fs layer
123ee413bb26: Downloading
422458d0aec9: Pulling fs layer
00230d3e4133: Waiting
0b5ec31f689b: Waiting
eee4b26ba47c: Waiting
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

[image]

Comment: what does `docker version` give you as output?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an issue with the most recent version of Docker. Reverting to an older version resolved the issue. Along with the problem I posted above, I was also getting errors similar to what is detailed here:

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-desktop-started-failing-to-start-for-windows-containers/135576